# "Kick your ass on the road" meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

I heard "Kick your ass on the road" in a movie. The context is that there were two people in a truck. One guy said it to the driver. From the context, I guess it probably means he had asked the driver to start off. I can't find it on the web. So, I want to ask if "Kick your ass on the road" is a common phrase? If so, what does it mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "start off"?  The "kick your ass" could mean either a physical beating (if both characters exited their vehicles), or it could mean to beat the other driver in a road race. It's unclear from your question what the context is.

Comment: @CanadianYankee I meant he asked the driver to drive the truck on the road. Can the sentence express that meaning?

Comment: So is the speaker a passenger?  It could be possible that he intends to berate the driver (that is, "kick his ass" in the sense of verbal punishment), but it's necessary to get the truck started first for other reasons.  So this doesn't mean "drive the truck on the road," but it could mean, "start driving now, and then I'll begin yelling at you [kicking your ass]."

Comment: @CanadianYankee yes, the speaker is a passenger. Your interpretation seems to make sense in that context. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Collins Dictionary

**[kick (someone's) ass](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/kick-someone-s-ass)**

> to punish or defeat someone

On the road is just setting the place where the defeat or the punishment may take place.

The speaker is saying to the driver that he (or maybe a third person) is going to defeat him.

> (I'm going to) Kick your ass on the road
>   (The Bad Guy is going to) Kick your ass on the road

More context is needed to specify who is the ass-kicker but I think that the main meaning of the expression is clear

Comment: That was what I thought, but the context doesn't seem to suggest this meaning.

Comment: @dan Thanks for accepting the answer but I think that you're not completely satisfied with it. Maybe if you indicate the movie and when that scene happens, you can get better help from others.

Comment: I think your answer is correct. The interpretation from Canadian Yankee is correct for that context.